# ICriteria - fluent nhibernate not producing inner join

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, icriteria

I am developing a small web application, using nhibnerate as my DAL.
I have to classes that I wish to select from, using a simple ICriteria.

This is a sample of my code:

```
var criteria = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(School))
    .CreateAlias("students", "s")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("s.Name", "Charley"));
```

From some reason this code generated a query with no inner join. I have only one table selected from.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I guess that you `School` class has a property name `Students`, right? Then the problem may be the lowercase "students" string. Well, it's just a guess, but I think it worth trying.

Comment: So put it into an answer, if it is the solution, it can't be accepted as a comment.

Comment: @vondip: it would help if you described your entities, and the actual generated SQL

Answer (score 2):

Oenning's comment may be the answer but you should also specify the join type in CreateAlias:

```
var criteria = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(School))
.CreateAlias("students", "s", JoinType.InnerJoin)
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("s.Name", "Charley"));
```

Comment: Still, no luck. I am using mysql as my database